# cell's accessoryType property being set but not respected during cell reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm creating a `UITableView` where some cells have their `accessoryType`property set to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.  This works fine for the initial load of the `UITableView` but falls apart during cell reuse.  The accessory is not displayed on certain cells.  I have debugged the code and verified, that when the `dataSource` calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as part of cell reuse, the `accessoryType` property is being set to the correct value.

I even tried hardcoding in something `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` before returning the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  This sets the accessory to the disclosure indicator the first time it is loaded, but loses it during reuse, even when hardcoded.

This feels like a rudimentary cell reuse issue, but I feel like I've covered all my bases in terms of making sure it's not a silly mistake.

`UITableViewDataSource` code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.puzzles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PuzzleListCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPuzzleListIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PuzzleListItem *item = self.puzzles[indexPath.row];
    [self.puzzleListItemCellPresenter presentCell:cell forItem:item];
    return cell;
}
```

relevant `viewDidLoad` snippet

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;   
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PuzzleListCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:kPuzzleListIdentifier];
```

annoying verbose method `presentCell:forItem:`

```
- (void)presentCell:(PuzzleListCell *)cell forItem:(PuzzleListItem *)listItem;
{
    cell.nameLabel.text = listItem.name;
    cell.puzzleStyleLabel.text = listItem.puzzleType == PuzzleTypeSliding ? @"Sliding" : @"Choosing";

    if (listItem.puzzleListItemType == PuzzleListItemTypeSent) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        UIFontDescriptor * italicDescriptor = [cell.nameLabel.font.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
        cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:italicDescriptor size:0];
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.puzzleStyleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        UIFontDescriptor * descriptor = [cell.nameLabel.font.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitUIOptimized];
        cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:0];

        if (listItem.played)
        {
            cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            cell.puzzleStyleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.puzzleStyleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

found the issue.  I realized it was probably an issue in my custom cell.

my cells' only method was `layoutSubviews` and I had apparently removed the call to `[super layoutSubviews]`.

Comment: Are you modifying `puzzleListItemType` or `played`, before calling `[tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: can you try this on a device ?

Comment: What do you mean by "falls apart during cell reuse"? What result do you see?

Comment: have you tried to change the `presentCell:forItem:` return type from **void** to **UITableViewCell**? So then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would call something like `return [self.puzzleListItemCellPresenter presentCell:cell forItem:item];`

Comment: @bhargavg I am not modifying those values.  They are set during `viewWillAppear`. @thndrkiss unfortunately I cannot.  @rdelmar,  the accessory's are not shown.  Even when I forcefully set each accessoryType to a specific one at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` some of them are still lost during reuse. @rlik I had that though too, but I verified in the debugger via `po cell.accessoryType` that the accessoryType is set right before the cell is returned.  I will try it though.. had the same idea.

Comment: @riik, confirmed that changing the return type of the presenter object to `PuzzleListCell` yields the same results

Comment: You cant rely on modifying the UITableViewCell directly, because of cell reuse. You should follow like this `Change the Model (PuzzleListItem in your case) -> call [tableView reloadData]`

Comment: @bhargavg this is exactly what cellForRowAtIndexPath is for... to set values on items inside the cell.  I'm currently NOT changing the model once the tableview is loaded.  I'm modifying the cell inside the presenter and the presenter is only used inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I could move the code into cellForRowAtIndexPath and see the same results

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't any of the controller code.  The issue was in my custom cell class.  I had not called `[super layoutSubviews]` . This makes complete sense as to why the accessory would be lost, as it is presumably a subview of the superclass

```
#import "PuzzleListCell.h"

@implementation PuzzleListCell

- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.puzzleStyleLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.nameLabel sizeToFit];
}
@end
```